# Download a file from a url

Tags: java, html, spring

My way of downloading a file from a docker is by using:

Backend

```
url = "http://" + settings.getDockerIP() + ":" + settings.getDockerPort() + "/containers/" + container.getId() + "/archive?path=/path";
```

Frontend

```
<div class="fm-file-icon">
    <a href="${file}"><img src="../resources/img/folder.png"></a>
  </div>
```

Controller

```
 @RequestMapping("/report")
public ModelAndView report(HttpServletRequest request) { 
    String environmentName = request.getParameter("name"); 
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("report");
    model.addObject("file", Report.getFileFromContainer(environmentName));

    return model;
}
```

The problem is that to download the file you also need a connection to `settings.getDockerIP():settings.getDockerPort()` and I don't want that. I just want to be able for the user to download the file by accessing the site without having the connection to the docker itself.

How can I do this? Maybe I need to download the file on the backend and then pass the url to the file in my server?

Comment: I assume you have a web server running on the Docker container and you want to be able to reach this server from the outside of the container, right?

Comment: the website has connection to the docker. But the user doesn't. I want to access that url and disponibilize the file to the user that doesn't have access.

Comment: What's the value of `href` attribute in your example?